# Select method and run directly the according post method

Tags: python, api, post, request, fastapi

I'm using FastAPI for Machine Leaning model deployment, I have two cases of models and each one has its own request post method, I want to make a menu of choice and run the selected method according to the clicked choice, the process should run as follow:

Select choice of method:

1. method_1

   or
2. method_2

   =>

   if method_1: run post method http://127.0.0.1:8000/method_1

   elif method_2: run post method http://127.0.0.1:8000/method_2

How can I achieve this (both menu of choice and the process of running the selected method) using only FastAPI with postman?

Comment: I'm not sure what're you looking for. Theoretically, generating two routes and using different models as handler, respectively, should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to create this menu using the same server that is hosting your choices, then you can create a new endpoint that returns an HTML response, in which contains two buttons for example each button has an OnClick action of hitting your other endpoints (Choices).